# AttributeError: module '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal' has no attribute 'TFE_NewContextOptions'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have run this code

```
python main.py configs/conv3d_sep2
```

get this error:

> TFE_NewContextOptions = _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.TFE_NewContextOptions
> AttributeError: module '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal' has no attribute 'TFE_NewContextOptions'

I am using tensorflow *1.13.1* and cuda *12.0*

I have tried all the methods suggested, but the error still appears. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Update your tensorflow version with this command, that should do the job

```
conda install tensorflow
```

Comment: did not work and i cannot install tensorflow version 1.13.1 by conda and it gives the error